# How to gradually interpolate smoothly between two yaw rotations in Minecraft MCP/Forge?

Tags: mathematics, rotation, minecraft-modding, interpolation

I am coding a custom client for Minecraft using MCP. (Please no hate, I'm not making a hacked client!) I have two variables `currentYaw` which is the current yaw rotation of the player, and `targetYaw` which is the yaw rotation that I want the player to be looking at. I have a function called `lerpAngle` and here is the code for it:

```
public static float lerpAngle(float fromRadians, float toRadians, float progress) {
    float delta = ((toRadians - fromRadians + PI2 + PI) % PI2) - PI;
    return (fromRadians + delta * progress + PI2) % PI2;
}
```

There is a float in `minecraft.timer` called `elapsedPartialTicks`. This variable is always between 0 and 1. Now I want to *interpolate* between `currentYaw` and `targetYaw` so that the transition is smooth. I passed in `elapsedPartialTicks` as `progress` but the screen moves way too fast. I am running all this code from the `tick` method.

What can I do to interpolate smoothly between `currentYaw` and `targetYaw`, but without the screen moving so fast.

Thank you for all the help!

Please note that I don't need any code, so it doesn't matter if you're answer is based on Forge or MCP. I just need a logic; I can write the code myself.

Again, thank you so much!

**EDIT:** In my current implementation, I have the following code:

```
float progress = (cameraInterpolationTimer.getCurrentTicks() + minecraft.timer.elapsedPartialTicks) / cameraInterpolationTimer.getTargetTicks();
minecraft.thePlayer.rotationYaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(InterpolationMath.angleLinearInterpolate((float) Math.toRadians(minecraft.thePlayer.rotationYaw), (float) Math.toRadians(yaw), progress));
minecraft.thePlayer.rotationPitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(InterpolationMath.angleLinearInterpolate((float) Math.toRadians(minecraft.thePlayer.rotationPitch), (float) Math.toRadians(pitch), progress));
```

The variables `pitch` and `yaw` are the rotations that I intend on facing. I also have variables `prevPitch` and `prevYaw`, which are set to `pitch` and `yaw` at the end of the function. `cameraInterpolationTimer` is a repeating timer (which is currently at a fixed interval) which gets reset when the difference between `yaw` and `prevYaw` is too large (because the target is moving; thus the `pitch` and `yaw` variables change each time the function is called). The function `getCurrentTicks` in the timer returns the amount of time that is passed since the timer was either created or reset. `getTargetTicks` is just another way of returning the fixed interval that the timer has been set for.

This should be interpolating smoothly to face the target yaw and pitch. It is working, but there is a mild stutter. It is pretty mild, but it is very annoying to look at and can be easily seen. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow down your progress. Let it take more than 1 tick (if I'm reading your situation right).

For example, when starting the transition - choose the desired tick duration (e.g. `tickDuration = 10` ticks) and store the `startedOnTick`. Now in the `lerp` you can lerp with the `progress = (currentTick + elapsedPartialTicks - startedOnTick) / tickDuration`. This way you will have your transition take more ticks and be longer.

Comment: It's kinda late for this now, but what if the final angle I want to look at changes every single tick?

Comment: @DayTrip if the angle changes, you can restart the lerping. You might also want to make `tickDuration` correlate with the difference between the current and target angles (so that smaller changes take less time to complete)

Comment: I attached what I tried in my question. There is still an issue :(